# Getting Object Load Error while opening EO from Jdeveloper

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I am pretty new to Oracle ADF, and I am working on an existing project. I want to add some attributes (via table) to an existing EO. But whenever I'm trying to open the EO from Jdeveloper, I am getting the following exception, and the EO remains uneditable.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at oracle.jbo.dt.objects.JboBaseObject.loadFromXMLFile(JboBaseObject.java:4403)
        ... 56 more
oracle.jbo.dt.objects.JboException: Object Load Error.
   Name: oracle.apps.financials.assets.additions.model.entity.AdditionInterfaceEO    
        at oracle.jbo.dt.objects.JboException.throwException(JboException.java:81)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.objects.JboBaseObject.loadFromXMLFile(JboBaseObject.java:4454)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.objects.JboBaseObject.getPDefObject(JboBaseObject.java:6260)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.objects.JboBaseObject.getPDefObject(JboBaseObject.java:6182)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.panels.JepNamePage.updatePDefObject(JepNamePage.java:472)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.panels.JepNamePage.refreshPanel(JepNamePage.java:356)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.entity.EoeNamePage.refreshPanel(EoeNamePage.java:178)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoEditorPage.callRefreshPanel(JeoEditorPage.java:141)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoPagedEditor.doRefreshPanel(JeoPagedEditor.java:461)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoPagedEditor.refreshPanel(JeoPagedEditor.java:452)
        at oracle.jbo.dt.jdevx.ui.editors.common.JeoEditorPage$1.run(JeoEditorPage.java:161)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
        at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
        at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

See the image description for the EO that I couldn't able to add any attribute:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: USer, tell us your exact JDev version, please!

Comment: It's 12.2.1.5.0

Comment: Please help me if you can!!

Comment: I'm not aware of an official version 12.2.1.5 at this time :( 
I don't have access to this version. Can you try the same using JDev 12.2.1.4?

Comment: No, I can't, since the version is installed in my VM, and I don't have permission to down/upgrade the version :(

Comment: Go in source mode at the bottom of your file and check if the XML is well-formed. If it is well-formed and the error still occur, you're going to have to do your modifications directly into the XML. Or ask your admin to install 12.2.1.4

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening for all tables or only for a single entity?

I have a similar issue with an older version of ADF. What happens is that my column names in the database table have longer than 20 characters in length and JDeveloper can't handle that, so for that case I make a manual edit of the EO or make the EO to be based on a view that uses the same table but with shorter column names.

Comment: Cool, thanks for your answer! You got the right point it seems! I'll definitely try your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I think this error could be fixed by update JDeveloper to newest version.